# Потеря данных при отправке POST запроса через AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, django

Пытаюсь разобрать в обработке запросов с использованием AJAX, при отправке запроса через JS, происходит добавление данных в БД, но я не могу их поймать и обработать как мне нужно, во view происходит исключение. При расшифровке запроса, передаваемые данные пустые. В чем моя ошибка, почему я не могу поймать передаваемые данные?

view.py

```
def UpdateMessage(request, chat_id):
    data = {
        'test': chat_id,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
       message = request.POST.get('message')
       slug = request.POST.get('slug_message')

       data['slug'] = slug
       data['message'] = message
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

`path('dialogs/<str:chat_id>/updateMessage/', UpdateMessage, name='update_message_url'),`

js

```
var innerMessage = document.getElementById('innerMessages');
    innerMessage.addEventListener('click', edit);

    function edit(event) {
        var targ = event.target.className === 'edit-message';
        if (targ) {
            var message = event.target.closest('.item-message-id');
            var data_id = message.getAttribute('data-message-id');
            var message_id = document.getElementById(data_id);
            var editInput = message.querySelector('input.edit-input');
            var btnEdit = message.querySelector('input.edit-message');
            var btnSave = message.querySelector('.btn-form');
            editInput.style.display = 'block';
            message_id.style.display = 'none';
            editInput.value = message_id.innerText;
            btnEdit.style.display = 'none';
            btnSave.style.display = 'block';
            btnSave.addEventListener('click', UpdateMessage);
        }
    }
    function UpdateMessage(event) {
        var targ = event.target.className === 'btn-form';
        if (targ) {
            var message = event.target.closest('.item-message-id');
            var data_id = message.getAttribute('data-message-id');
            var message_id = document.getElementById(data_id);
            var editInput = message.querySelector('input.edit-input');
            var btnEdit = message.querySelector('input.edit-message');
            var btnSave = message.querySelector('.btn-form');
            var slug = message.getAttribute('data-message-slug');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    slug_message: slug,
                    message: editInput.value
                },
                success: function () {
                    editInput.style.display = 'none';
                    message_id.style.display = 'block';
                    btnEdit.style.display = 'block';
                    btnSave.style.display = 'none';
                    message_id.innerHTML = editInput.value;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

html

```
        <div data-message-id="{{ message_id }}" data-message-slug="{{ message_item.slug_message }}" 
       class="item-message-id">
            <p id="{{ message_id }}">{{ message_item.message|safe }}</p>
            <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 90%" class="edit-message" value="редактировать">
            <form action="{% url 'update_message_url' chat.id %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" style="display: none" class="edit-input">
                <button style="margin-left: 90%; display: none" class="btn-form">сохранить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

errors

```
"POST /dialogs/1/updateMessage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 44
----------------------------------------

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 62484)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Jony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
```

JSON который я получаю на выходе

```
{"test": "1", "slug": null, "message": null}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function UpdateMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
  $.ajax({
    url: ???
```

Comment: ```event.preventDefault()``` помогло, исключения нет, url он пока автоматом ставит, в зависимости от той страницы на которой находится.